# Protractor: How to select a input element inside a shadow DOM (Polymer) which is under multiple layer of shadow root

Tags: protractor, shadow-dom

I'm using Protractor 5.4.2 to test webpages created using Polymer.js.
I have a Webpage with multiple level Shadow roots. I have to select an input which lies under 10th shadow-root. To traverse to the 10th level, I need to move from the first shadow root or I can directly access the 10th shadow root?

[image: Developer tool > Element]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem with shadow DOM. I used by.js (http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.js) locator to run my custom js code on the page. And result of that is ElementFinder that actually represents shadow dom inner element.

```
class HomePage {
   get shadowRoot(): ElementFinder {
        return element(
            By.js(function (elem) {
                try {
                    // querySelectorAll returns array-like object, so converting it to Array with this:
                    return Array.prototype.slice.call(
                        document.querySelector(elem).shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#mdr-ibe')
                    );
                } catch (err) {
                    // using try/catch to avoid uncaught errors
                    return [];
                }
            }, 'css-locator-of-element-with-shadow-root')
        );
    }

    public async startSearch() {
        // Using chaining to search for elements inside shadowRoot:
        const startSearchButton = this.shadowRoot.$('button.start-search')
        await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(startSearchButton));
        await startSearchButton.click();
    }
}
```

But keep in mind - working with shadow root elements does not work well in firefox